# Transparency of ModelVisual3D with DiffuseMaterial

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I come across a problem which seems a bug for me. I'm making an app that visualizes atoms in  a crystal. That problem is that it draws a transparent object and hides the object behind.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
        foreach (var atom in filteredAtoms)
        {
            var color = new Color();

            color.ScR = (float)atom.AluminiumProbability;
            //color.G = 50;
            color.ScB = (float)atom.MagnesiumProbability;
            //setting alpha channel but Opacity doens't work as well
            color.ScA = (float)(1.0 - atom.VacancyProbability); //(float)1.0;//
            DiffuseMaterial material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(color));
            //material.Brush.Opacity = 1.0 - atom.VacancyProbability;

            // make visuals and add them to
            atomBuldier.Add(new Point3D(atom.X * Atom.ToAngstrom, atom.Y * Atom.ToAngstrom, atom.Z * Atom.ToAngstrom), material);
        }
```

When I change the material to e.g. EmissiveMaterial there are no "cut" atoms. I googled [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6d7da6bb-3b97-4e2f-9e55-f3128ceef69b), but the advices given don't apply to this case.

Is this a bug with 2D brush applied to 3D?

The full source code can be found here http://alloysvisualisation.codeplex.com the dll and a test file http://alloysvisualisation.codeplex.com/releases beta link.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Lunch app
2. Click Open file button
3. Open test file (xyzT2000.chmc)
4. Click Mask button
5. Check 11 (series of atoms are almost transparent)
6. Ckick Redraw

Comment: I seem to remember something about WPF 3D objects having a front material and a back material, are you setting both of them?

Comment: In class Sphere3D : ModelVisual3D I added             set
            {
                (this.Content as GeometryModel3D).Material = value;
                (this.Content as GeometryModel3D).BackMaterial = value;
            } but the effect is the same

Comment: it seems they are not rendered when intersect and one of then is transparent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the transparent atoms, you must disable z-buffer-writing. *I'm unfamiliar with WPF, but you can probably set this in an Appearance or Material object or so.*

The problem occurs because of the following:

When a transparent atom is rendered, it writes its depth to the z-buffer. Subsequent non-transparent atoms that are rendered and should appear, do not get written to the frame buffer, because their z-values fail the z-test, because of the z-values already in the z-buffer of the transparent atom.

In short, the graphics card treats the transparent atom as opaque and hides anything behind it.

**Edit**: Upon looking into WPF it seems pretty high-level, without direct control of z-buffer behavior.

According to [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/C3A5C288-F31E-42E0-BF2C-ED48E7452EF1), the emissive and specular materials do not write to the z-buffer, so using those is your solution when working with transparent objects.

Comment: Thank I found this link after your post as well :)

Comment: Here is a link with some nice pictures showing this problem: http://www.ab4d.com/TransparencySorting.aspx. As that link points out, it's not always necessary to disable z buffer writing (or to use emissive or specular materials). If you can order the viewport children such that objects further from the camera drawn first, you don't get this z buffer interference. In theory this means juggling the object order whenever the camera changes, but in practice you may have a simpler situation where the objects always render in a given order.